# Passing variables in wordpress using add_rewrite_tag()

Tags: php, wordpress

I have searched so much for the perfect way to use add_rewrite_rule() with add_rewrite_tag()

after reading wordpress documentation i have reached to this point

in my function.php :

```
function custom_rewrite_tag() {
  add_rewrite_tag('%variable1%', '([^&]+)');
  add_rewrite_tag('%variable2%', '([^&]+)');
  add_rewrite_tag('%variable3%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);

function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^testpage/([^/]*)/?$','index.php?page_id=9&variable1=$matches[1]','top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^testpage/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$','index.php?page_id=9&variable1=$matches[1]&variable2=$matches[2]','top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^testpage/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$','index.php?page_id=9&variable1=$matches[1]&variable2=$matches[2]&variable3=$matches[3]','top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

Now, i am trying to get the values of variable 1,2 and 3 to use it in my testpage.php

i used this :

```
global $wp_query;
echo $wp_query->query_vars['variable1'];
echo $wp_query->query_vars['variable2'];
echo $wp_query->query_vars['variable3'];
```

The Problem :

is that the only variable i can get is variable 1 ?

i can't get neither variable2 nor variable3

NOTE : using $_GET[] or $_POST[] isn't working